# How I can do to read the tag value for my persistence.xml <jta-data-source> in from a file config.properties

Tags: java, properties, config, persistence.xml

I want to do something like this:

**config.properties:**

```
dsname=value;
anotherValue=anotherValue;
```

**persitence.xml**

```
<jta-data-source>${dsname}</jta-data-source>
```

Comment: Are these files used with any library, or will you read them directly from a java code?

Comment: What is the question? What didn't work?

Answer (score -1):

The properties file is outside of my web project, I am using JPA with EclipseLink but I need to **initialize the parameter jta-data-source from the external file value "dsname"**

actually:

```
<persistence-unit name="Unit-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>datasource</jta-data-source>
      <class>Clase1</class>
      <class>Clase2</class>
      <class>Clase3</class>
  <properties/>
</persistence-unit>
```

idea to make:

```
<persistence-unit name="Unit-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>${dsname}</jta-data-source>
      <class>Clase1</class>
      <class>Clase2</class>
      <class>Clase3</class>
  <properties/>
</persistence-unit>
```